Can I solve the drag equation without any experimental data? (I have a 3d model of a rocket and want to see how fast it can go using math)
I made a rocket in a cad software and  tried to do the math to solve speed. Is there any way to solve the drag coefficient of a rocket (pointed for simplicity) cone and fins that goes up then goes to an edge.
Is there a formula to solve this?
I have already solved the speed of the rocket using a simple force vs weight calculator and got around 900 mph
I have already tried the equations online yet I do not know if the ref area is the side profile or the top down view and I feel as though I would still struggle with the values. Can I have help?

The reference area moving upward is the top down view. You probaly don't intend for the rocket to move sideways. But you'll have to guess the drag coefficient, maybe 0.5. If you have a supercomputer, a sophisticated hydrodynamics code, and the expertise to use it, you might be able to get a better estimate.
